# Python script to match a partcular text in filename and count the number of such files

Tags: python

In a folder I have files containing file names as the following :

```
Q1234_ABC_B02_12232.hl7

12313_SDDD_Q03_44545.hl7

Q43434_SAD_B02_2312.hl7

4324_SDSD_W05_344423423.hl7

3123123_DSD_D06_67578.hl7
```

and many such files

I need to write a python script to count the number of files whose file names begin with "Q" and which have "B02" after the second underscore which means that I should get output count as 2. I have tried the following script but not got the desired solution.

```
    import re
    import os

resultsDict = {}
myString1 = ""
regex = r'[^_]+_([^_]*)_.*'
for file_name in os.listdir("."):

m = file_name.split("_")

if len(m) > 2 :
   myString = m[2]

   if "B02" in myString:
   myString1 = myString

   if myString1 in resultsDict:
       resultsDict[myString1] += 1
   else:
       resultsDict.update({myString1: 1})
else:
print "error in the string! there are less then 2 _"

print resultsDict
```

I am using  python 2.6.6. Any help would be useful.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with [tag:bash]. Removed that tag.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: Too bad you removed bash, because that has the simplest answer: `ls | grep -c -E '^Q([^_]*_){2}B02'`. You were right to remove it, though.

Comment: @camh As far as I understand it is _required_ to have a Python answer. But maybe not. If you feel the need, don't hesitate to add that tag again.

Answer (score 1):

As time of this writing, there is several answer with a wrong regex.

One of these is *probably* better:

```
r'^Q[^_]*_[^_]*_B02_.*'

r'^Q[^_]*_[^_]*_B02.*'

r'^Q[^_]*_[^_]*_B02(_.*|$)'
```

If you stick with `.*` instead, the regex might consume some intermediate underscore. So your are no longer able to enforce `B02` being after the *second* `_`

After that, test for matching values ([`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match)) is a simple loop over the various file names ( [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) or [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob)). Here is an example using list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [file for file in os.listdir(".") if re.match(r'^Q[^_]*_[^_]*_B02.*', file)]
>>> l
['Q1234_ABC_B02_12232.hl7', 'Q43434_SAD_B02_2312.hl7']
>>> len(l)
2
```

For better performances you might wish to compile the regex first ([`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile)).

---

As a comment by @camh above let me think that maybe you have jumped into Python because you couldn't find a shell-based solution, here is how to do the same thing using only bash:

```
sh$ shopt -s extglob
sh$ ls Q*([^_])_*([^_])_B02*
Q1234_ABC_B02_12232.hl7  Q43434_SAD_B02_2312.hl7
sh$ ls Q*([^_])_*([^_])_B02* | wc -l
#                            ^^^^^^^
# This *won't* work if some file names contain '\n' !!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression,

```
import re
resultsDict = {}
expression = "^Q.*_.*_B02_.*"
p = re.compile(expression)
for file_name in os.listdir("."):
    if p.match(file_name):
        if file_name in resultsDict:
            resultsDict[file_name] = resultsDict[file_name] + 1
        else:
            resultsDict[file_name] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this regular expression:

```
'^Q.*_.*_B02_.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will match all files in current directory according to your requirements.

```
import os
import re

regex = r'^Q\w+_\w+_B02'   # This will match any word character between the underscores

for f in os.listdir("."):
    if re.match(regex, f, re.I):
       print f
```

- Word character is A-Z, a-z and 0-9.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with list comprehensions instead of regular expressions. First, get all the directory names that start with Q, and split them on the underscores;

```
import os

dirs = [d.split('_') for d in os.listdir(".") if d.startswith('Q')]
```

Now get all directories with two underscores or more;

```
dirs = [d for d in dirs if len(d) > 2]
```

Finally, narrow it down;

```
dirs = [d for d in dirs if d[2] == 'B02']
```

You could combine the last to comprehensions into one;

```
dirs = [d for d in dirs if len(d) > 2 and d[2] == 'B02']
```